# Aggregating using proc means SAS

Tags: sas, proc, sas-studio

For a project, I have a large dataset of 1.5m entries, I am looking to aggregate some car loan data by some constraint variables such as:

Country, Currency, ID, Fixed or floating , performing ,  Initial Loan Value , Car Type , Car Make

I am wondering if it is possible to aggregate data by summing the initial loan value for the numeric and then condensing the similar variables into one row with the same observation such that I turn the first dataset into the second

```
Country Currency ID Fixed_or_Floating Performing Initial_Value Current_Value 

data have;
set have;
input country $ currency $ ID Fixed $ performing $ initial current;
datalines;

UK       GBP     1   Fixed     Performing          100    50    
UK       GBP     1   Fixed     Performing          150    30   
UK       GBP     1   Fixed     Performing          160    70   
UK       GBP     1   Floating Performing          150    30   
UK       GBP     1   Floating Performing          115    80   
UK       GBP     1   Floating Performing          110    60   
UK       GBP     1   Fixed     Non-Performing   100    50 
UK       GBP     1   Fixed     Non-Performing   120    30  
;
run;

data want;
set have;
input country $ currency $ ID Fixed $ performing $ initial current;
datalines;

UK GBP 1 Fixed Performing 410 150
UK GBP 1 Floating Performing 275 170
UK GBP 1 Fixed Non-performing 220 80
;
run;
```

Essentially looking for a way to sum the numeric values while concatenating the character variables.

I've tried this code

```
proc means data=have sum;
var initial current;
by country currency id fixed performing;
run;
```

Unsure If i'll have to use a proc sql (would be too slow for such a large dataset) or possibly a data step.

any help in concatenating would be appreciated.

Comment: So what is the question? Did the `Proc MEANS` not work ? Was there an error message? Are you unsatisfied with the resource use of the proc step ? 1.5m entries, is that the number of distinct ID values in `have`, or the number of rows (`nobs`)?  If 1.5m distinct ids, what is nobs ?

Answer (score 1):

Create an output data set from `Proc MEANS` and concatenate the variables in the result. MEANS with a BY statement requires sorted data.  Your `have` does not.

Concatenation of the aggregations key (those lovely categorical variables) into a single space separated key (not sure why you need to do that) can be done with `CATX` function.

```
data have_unsorted;
length country $2 currency $3 id 8 type $8 evaluation $20 initial current 8;
input country currency ID type evaluation initial current;
datalines;
UK       GBP     1   Fixed     Performing          100    50    
UK       GBP     1   Fixed     Performing          150    30   
UK       GBP     1   Fixed     Performing          160    70   
UK       GBP     1   Floating Performing          150    30   
UK       GBP     1   Floating Performing          115    80   
UK       GBP     1   Floating Performing          110    60   
UK       GBP     1   Fixed     Non-Performing   100    50 
UK       GBP     1   Fixed     Non-Performing   120    30  
;
run;
```

**Way 1 - MEANS with CLASS/WAYS/OUTPUT, post process with data step**

The cardinality of the class variables *may* cause problems.

```
proc means data=have_unsorted noprint;
  class country currency ID type evaluation ;
  ways 5;
  output out=sums sum(initial current)= / autoname;
run;

data want;
  set sums;
  key = catx(' ',country,currency,ID,type,evaluation);
  keep key initial_sum current_sum;
run;
```

**Way 2 - SORT followed by MEANS with BY/OUTPUT, post process with data step**

BY statement requires sorted data.

```
proc sort data=have_unsorted out=have;
  by country currency ID type evaluation ;

proc means data=have noprint;
  by country currency ID type evaluation ;
  output out=sums sum(initial current)= / autoname;
run;

data want;
  set sums;
  key = catx(' ',country,currency,ID,type,evaluation);
  keep key initial_sum current_sum;
run;
```

**Way 3 - MEANS, given data that is grouped but unsorted, with BY NOTSORTED/OUTPUT, post process with data step**

The `have` rows will be processed in *clumps* of the `BY` variables. A clump is a sequence of contiguous rows that have the same by group.

```
proc means data=have_unsorted noprint;
  by country currency ID type evaluation NOTSORTED;
  output out=sums sum(initial current)= / autoname;
run;

data want;
  set sums;
  key = catx(' ',country,currency,ID,type,evaluation);
  keep key initial_sum current_sum;
run;
```

**Way 4 - DATA Step, DOW loop, BY NOTSORTED and key construction**

The `have` rows will be processed in *clumps* of the `BY` variables. A clump is a sequence of contiguous rows that have the same by group.

```
data want_way4;
  do until (last.evaluation);
    set have;
    by country currency ID type evaluation NOTSORTED;
    initial_sum = SUM(initial_sum, initial);
    current_sum = SUM(current_sum, current);
  end;
  key = catx(' ',country,currency,ID,type,evaluation); 
  keep key initial_sum current_sum;
run;
```

**Way 5 - Data Step hash**

data can be processed with out a presort or clumping.  In other words, data can be totally disordered.

```
data _null_;
  length key $50 initial_sum current_sum 8;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    call missing (key, initial_sum, current_sum);

    declare hash sums();
    sums.defineKey('key');
    sums.defineData('key','initial_sum','current_sum');
    sums.defineDone();
  end;

  set have_unsorted end=end;
  key = catx(' ',country,currency,ID,type,evaluation); 

  rc = sums.find();
  initial_sum = SUM(initial_sum, initial);
  current_sum = SUM(current_sum, current);
  sums.replace();

  if end then
    sums.output(dataset:'have_way5');
run;
```

Comment: proc summary data=testa nway;
    var  net_balance;
    class ID fixed performing reference initial current country currency;
output out=sumtest sum=sum_initial;
run;

Answer (score 0):

1.5m entries is not very big dataset. The dataset is sorted first.

```
proc sort data=have;
by country currency id fixed performing;
run;

proc means data=have sum;
var initial current;
by country currency id fixed performing;
output out=sum(drop=_:) sum(initial)=Initial sum(current)=Current;
run;
```

Comment: it was sorted by ID, fixed, performing, country currency

Answer (score -1):

Props to paige miller

```
proc summary data=testa nway;
var  net_balance;
class ID fixed_or_floating performing_status initial country currency ;
output out=sumtest sum=sum_initial;
run;
```

Comment: This isn't different than any of the answers you have above. In fact it doesn't align with your original post because the EBA_segment isn't mentioned anywhere else.

Comment: My apologies, I mistakenly put that instead of ID

Comment: Based on this answer your question was actually: how do I save the output to data set and get results for multiple variables at once. Proc summary, means, univariate would all work as indicated by others. The other answers are more correct than yours.